# three.js - Model showing with blank (black) texture despite material loaded

Tags: three.js, 3d

I have a 3D model file `3dbaotang.obj` and a material file `3dbaotang.mtl`. I've loaded both of them using `three.js` OBJLoader and MTLLoader. The model has shown up, but not the material, as it's solely covered with black. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)', 1.0);
var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)', 0.75);
var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();
keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);
fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.update();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, false);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xf2f2f2), 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// LOAD MODEL
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setResourcePath('/models/');
mtlLoader.setPath('/models/');
mtlLoader.load('/3dbaotang.mtl', (materials) => {
    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('/models/');
    objLoader.load('3dbaotang.obj', (object) => {
        scene.add(object);
    });
});

camera.position.z = 200;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: I have the same problem, even with added light, whether it is ambient, spotlight, or pointlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the lack of light that caused this problem, not the material. After adding `ambient light` to the scene, the object can be seen normally

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Brother Eye's answer, I'm brand new and and spent quite a lot of time in the dark but this got me on to the solution so I thought I'd elaborate for anyone in the same position.

Adding a light can be some simply as follows;

```
//Add light
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(light);
```

The reference docs are located at https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/AmbientLight